# filter data according to class names in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs and here is my view :

```
<div style="width:70px;">
                               Show Online <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showonline" />
                            </div>

<div ng-repeat="user in users|filter:showonline">
<span type="button" class="{(isOnline()) ? 'available' : 'unavailable'}">user.id</span>
</div>
```

above code will generate html like this inside the div containing ng-repeat:

```
<span type="button" class="available">111</span>
<span type="button" class="available">121</span>
<span type="button" class="unavailable">88</span>
<span type="button" class="available">878</span>
```

the classes are assigned according to the online status of the user. by default the above code displays all the  elements having class available and unavailable. I want to use a checkbox as a filter which will display the  based on the class name(if checkbox is clicked then display  with classname available which will show only the online users). And when I uncheck the filter checkbox then all the  having classes available and unavailable should be displayed.
I know how to filter data in angularjs but I have no idea how to filter data by classname using a checkbox.
 How do I do it?

Comment: Share a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more variable `showAvailable` to your scope to show the available users.
Also, I added one more parameter to object called `isOnline` which should be added because you don't need to check again and again.

Here is the check I added to HTML : `ng-show="!showAvailable || user.isOnline"`

Demo:

```js
function TodoCrtl($scope) {

  $scope.users = [{
    userid: 1,
    isOnline: true
  }, {
    userid: 2,
    isOnline: false
  }, {
    userid: 3,
    isOnline: true
  }]
  this.name = "AngularJS";
  $scope.showAvailable = false;

}
```

```css
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.available {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.unavailable {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCrtl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users|filter:showonline">
      <span type="button" ng-show="!showAvailable || user.isOnline" ng-class="user.isOnline ? 'available' : 'unavailable'">{{user.userid +' '+ (user.isOnline ? 'available' : 'unavailable')}}</span>
    </div>
    Show Available only: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showAvailable" />
    
  </div>
</div>
```